# C# bouncing cubes game, remove cubes from 100px of the center

Tags: c#, monogame

I am making a small "game" in Monogame with C# of 2000 blocks that bounce around the screen. I need to make the cubes disappear if they are within a circle 100px of the center of the screen. The 2 classes i have are (Game1.cs) which is the game itself, and then (Block.cs) which is the code for the blocks bouncing around the screen, here is the code for both:

Game1.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Inlämning2
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
        Texture2D pixelTexture;
        List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var block = new Block();
                block.X = rnd.Next(0, 600);
                block.Y = rnd.Next(0, 400);
                block.Color = new Color(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
                blocks.Add(block);
            }
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            pixelTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pixel");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            foreach (Block block in blocks)
            {
                block.Update();
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _spriteBatch.Begin();
            foreach (Block block in blocks)
            {
                block.Draw(_spriteBatch, pixelTexture);
            }
            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}

---------------------------------------------Block.cs:--------------------------------------------


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Inlämning2
{
    class Block
    {
        public int X { get; set; } = 100;
        public int Y { get; set; } = 100;
        public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Red;
        public int speed1 = 1;
        public int speed2 = -1;

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(X, Y, 30, 30), Color);
        }

        public void Update()
        {
                if (X< 0) speed2 += 1;
                if (X > 770) speed2 += -1;
                if (Y > 450) speed1 += -1;
                if (Y< 0) speed1 += 1;
                X += speed2;
                Y += speed1;
                if (speed1 > 1) speed1 = 1;
                if (speed2 > 1) speed2 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that checks the position of the cube. What is the question?

Comment: That is what i need help with, i am unsure how to make the code for that

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69251464/remove-objects-when-they-are-in-a-certain-area , oddly enough, both questions share the same specifics.

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd

Comment: But that doesn't help me, that post has no approved solution

Comment: Have you tried out the existing answer, and did it help you in the right direction? It doesn't need to be approved to be useful. 'Approved' answers are only there to make sure the questioner is satisfied.

Comment: @Steven,  This is a homework question asked by the same professor or curriculum, in different semesters. This question has code, but still asks us to be a coding service.

Comment: @Blackout: I'd recommend reviewing [Stack Overflow's guidelines for asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the center of the screen as a Vector2 called Center.

```
//pseudo C# code:
if (Center - X,Y).LengthSquared() < 100 * 100) //fix this line
```

... then remove block `Blocks.Remove(this)`, not possible during an enumeration, find another way.

If the question is referring to Manhattan Distance the formula: `if((Math.Abs(Center.X -X) + Math.Abs(Center.Y -Y))< 100)`
would apply.